# IOS: app music background

Tags: ios, xcode, mp3

I want to insert a music inside my app, It should start when app start and it's ok; but for example if this mp3 is about 3 minutes; what can i do to restart this mp3?
I suppose that I should control it in appDelegate...but what's the way to restart the mp3?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AVAudioPlayer? If so, can't you just set the numberOfLoops to -1?

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;